# rendering reStructuredText in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, restructuredtext

we are developing a application using reactjs and we want the content to be developed by subject matter experts. we are considering to use reStructuredText to be used by the content (mostly text) developers. is there a way to render this in reactjs... another alternative is to use markdown, but that has very basic features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reactjs does not interpret reStructuredText. You would need a tool to do that first, such as [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) to parse the source files into whatever static output format, then use whatever to serve the generated content.